# How can i pass and display data from one component to other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is my first post on stackoverflow.

I'm new in reactJS and currently trying to create a fruit list where a Header component displays an input field and a button, where you can write the name of the fruit that you want and add on your list, only if the json file contains the fruit name. Then a Main component should display these selected fruits as a list.

But i'm facing an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Main

  2 | 
  3 | const Main = ({ list }) => {
  4 |   return (
> 5 |     <div>
  6 |       {list.map(item => (
  7 |         <li key={item.id}>
  8 |           {item.name}
```

Header Component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import jsonData from "./db.json";
import Main from "./Main";

function Header() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const handleSearch = (fruit) => {
    const searchedFruit = jsonData.find((item) => item.name === fruit);
    if (searchedFruit) {
      setList([...list, searchedFruit]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="Search">
      <header className="Search_header">
      </header>
      <h1>Fruit Market</h1>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}></input>
      <button onClick={() => handleSearch(name)}>Search</button>
      <h2>My list of fruits:</h2>

      <Main list={list} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Main component

```
const Main = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.name}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this error in an isolated code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) environment?

Comment: the only problem you have when the component render first time list is an empty object and in the main page you try to list.map for an empty array fist check the length of the array

Comment: @HamzaMiloudAmar That is not the OP's issue. if array's values is `[]` the map will work but not render anything. It will not throw an error. The error clearly says that `list` is `undefined`

Comment: @johnjoker13 do you see this error when the app/Header component initially mounts, or after you try and perform a search?

Comment: try to add console.log in the main to see what is the value of list

Comment: @CharlieStanard https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-merkle-obkuc

Comment: @johnjoker13 - I've set up a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-clarke-tohd3. This is essentially your exact code with only a few minor adjustments to make it work in the sandbox. Everything appears to work correctly, so your error is likely being caused by something else not related to the code you've provided.

Comment: @HamzaMiloudAmar I changed some things in my index.js and add a console.log in the Main and worked. Thanks!

Comment: i think the problem you have from codesandbox is you need to left you state up  because the list state exist in the header and the header exist with the same level of main

Comment: no problem and am very sorry for the first incorrect reply because i want to do with fast to gain some reputation (-_-)

Comment: @CharlieStanard Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to check if any elements in array before `mapping`.
I think react tries to map it while rendering for the first time but it is empty,
you can simply handle this error by adding:

```
{list.length && list.map(item => ...)}
```

You can become more familiar with conditional rendering in react by reading [this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).